# How do you remove the two slash in different position

Tags: python

I have string like this

```
ab/acd/ad//ab/da
```

I just need remove the two slash from center but not single one like this:

```
ab/acd/adab/da
```

If I do string.replace('/', '') it gives

```
abacdadabda
```

which is not what i want..

thanx

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to replace the double slash with a single:

```
string.replace('//', '/')
```

Alternatively, split the string on `/`, remove empty elements and re-join:

```
'/'.join([p for p in string.split('/') if p])
```

This also handles strings with many consecutive slashes.

Demo:

```
>>> string = 'ab/acd/ad//ab/da'
>>> string.replace('//', '/')
'ab/acd/ad/ab/da'
>>> '/'.join([p for p in string.split('/') if p])
'ab/acd/ad/ab/da'
>>> string = 'foo/bar///baz/////spam'
>>> '/'.join([p for p in string.split('/') if p])
'foo/bar/baz/spam'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the slash string in your replace method to a double slash. This makes it only look for sections of string where two slashes are next to each other and ignore a single slash, like below.

> > > string = "ab/acd/ad//ab/da"
> > >
> > > string.replace('//','')
> > >
> > > "ab/acd/adab/da"